# sprite feature in XTK

Tags: three.js, xtk

Is it possible to add sprite feature in XTK ?

I need to render large number of point data. I was able to render it as X.displayable.types.POINTS. But it would be great if i can render the points with texture. I am looking for something similar to the one available with three.js
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Sprite.js

Comment: I didn't try the Three.js sprites. Could you elaborate on a use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following example which is kind of a sprites approach. The difference is that still each object gets pushed separately to the shaders so that it is rather slow. This is due to XTK's background of being optimized for rendering large objects than a lot of objects.

http://jsfiddle.net/haehn/jjzuD/